# Can't insert data into logstash via python

Tags: python, logging, logstash, elk, python-logging

I've been researching some log tools and i've found the ELK stack, for a quick test i used the following [git](https://github.com/deviantony/docker-elk) to create an environment for testing, i am testing on a log module which is structured as shown below:

```
.
|-- Logger
|   |-- Log
|   |   |-- __init__.py
|   |   |-- metaLogger.py
|   |   `-- singleton.py
|   |-- __main__.py
|   |-- requirements
|   |   `-- requirements.txt
|   `-- __version__.py
|-- MANIFEST
`-- setup.py
```

And the packages used are:

```
jmespath==0.10.0
python-dateutil==2.8.1
python-logstash==0.4.6
six==1.15.0
urllib3==1.26.3
```

The *singleton.py* file is a simple class just to assert that i have only one log instance:

```
class Singleton(object):
    """
    Singleton interface:
    https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.2.3/descrintro/#__new__
    """

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwds):
        it = cls.__dict__.get("__it__")
        if it is not None:
            return it
        cls.__it__ = it = object.__new__(cls)
        it.init(*args, **kwds)
        return it

    def init(self, *args, **kwds):
        pass
```

The *metaLogger.py* is basically where resides most of the config, and for some reason i had to override the makePickle function from TCPLogstashHandler due to an string to bytes error:

```
import logging
from os import environ, getpid
from logstash import TCPLogstashHandler
from Log.singleton import Singleton
import sys

class ModifiedTCPLogstashHandler(TCPLogstashHandler):
    def makePickle(self, record):
        """Override function to convert string to binary
        """
        return str.encode(self.formatter.format(record)) + b"\n"


class MetaLogger(Singleton):
    """
    Logger metaclass.
    """

    def init(self, robotname: str, loggername: str, loggerlevel):
        self.logger = logging.getLogger(loggername)

        self.logger.setLevel(loggerlevel)
        formatter = logging.Formatter(
            fmt="%(asctime)s | %(levelname)s | %(name)s :: %(message)s",
            datefmt="%F %H:%M:%S",
        )

        logstash_handler = ModifiedTCPLogstashHandler(
            "http://localhost",
            5044,
            version=1
        )
        logstash_handler.setFormatter(formatter)

        console_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
        console_handler.setFormatter(formatter)

        self.logger.addHandler(console_handler)
        self.logger.addHandler(logstash_handler)
        print(sys.version)
        print(getpid())

    def critical(self, loggername: str, msg: str) -> None:
        self.logger = logging.getLogger(loggername)
        self.logger.critical(msg, exc_info=1)

    def debug(self, loggername: str, msg: str) -> None:
        self.logger = logging.getLogger(loggername)
        self.logger.debug(msg)

    def error(self, loggername: str, msg: str) -> None:
        self.logger = logging.getLogger(loggername)
        self.logger.error(msg, exc_info=1)

    def info(self, loggername: str, msg: str) -> None:
        self.logger = logging.getLogger(loggername)
        self.logger.info(msg)

    def warning(self, loggername: str, msg: str) -> None:
        self.logger = logging.getLogger(loggername)
        self.logger.warning(msg)
```

And finally i have the *__main__.py* which is basically a implementation and test file for the time being:

```
from logging import INFO
from Log.metaLogger import MetaLogger


class Logger(object):
    def __init__(
        self,
        robotname:str = "NULL",
        loggername: str = "root",
        loggerlevel=INFO
    ) -> "Logger":
        """
        Logger impelmentation class.
        """
        self.logger = MetaLogger(robotname, loggername, loggerlevel)
        self.loggername = loggername

    def critical(self, msg: str) -> None:
        self.logger.critical(self.loggername, msg)

    def debug(self, msg: str) -> None:
        self.logger.debug(self.loggername, msg)

    def error(self, msg: str) -> None:
        self.logger.error(self.loggername, msg)

    def info(self, msg: str) -> None:
        self.logger.info(self.loggername, msg)

    def warning(self, msg: str) -> None:
        self.logger.warning(self.loggername, msg)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    logger = Logger(loggername="TEST_LOGGER_LOGSTASH")
    logger.info("This is an info")
    logger.warning("this is a warning")
    logger.error("this is an error")
    logger.critical("This is a critical error")
```

For some reason the module seems to be running fine, without a single error message, but when i check the kibana dashboard and the elasticsearch database i can't find the logs, i also read the logs from the logstash but i can't find the error.